# Retrieve Attendee Address details from Eventbrite v3 API

Tags: c#, javascript, c#-4.0, eventbrite

I'm trying to retrieve **address information** and **home phone** of attendees though the endpoint "**https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/{eventId}/attendees/?token={token}**".

But in the response i did not find the address information of any attendee though i had added the address fields. In response, i found a **profile** key which gave me the "**cell_phone**" but still no luck with the home phone or the address details.

The address details i'm taking about is the country, address, city, state, zipcode. i'm not able to find the same within the documents. i'm using the new version of api, the old version had event_list_attendees method which listed all the information i needed.

I would want the same response which "event_list_attendees" gave. Is there any method in the new API which would do the same.

Am i missing some step or the **v3** API doesn't return these field ?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Well i found that this is a bug with the new version of API. we have raised a ticket with the eventbrite team and this would be taken care of shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, they say they are aware and are updating the API - its currently only in preview!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old, but just wanted to let you know that the issue has been resolved and you can now access all Attendee address information.